# send email with powershell issue

Tags: powershell

Ian using below PowerShell to send email
test work form wins10  but form windows server2016 it wont works

```
$Username  = "XXX@XXX.com"
$EmailPassword = "XXX"
$Attachment= "D:\test\test.txt"
$EmailTo = "YYY@YYY.com" 
$EmailFrom   = "XXX@XXX.com" 
$Subject = "PowershellTest"
$Body= "PowershellTest"
$SMTPServer  = "smtp.office365.com"  
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) 
$Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

I got below error

```
 Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
 At line:15 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

I idea

Thanks

Comment: Inspect the exception to discover the cause of the failure: `$Error[0].Exception |Format-List * -Force` (you may have to inspect `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` as well)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved
it looks that this function does not support TLS 1.2
I enable TL 1.0 and it works normally

Thanks